# Trying to watch Netflix on Debian using Firefox

Tags: firefox, debian, netflix, drm, stretch

I am using Debian Stretch and and Firefox 60.5.0esr (64-bit). Widevine and OpenH264 are installed in Add-ons and I toggled 'Play DRM-controlled content' in Preferences. However I am still unable to use Netflix on my browser. The alert 'Firefox is installing components needed to play the audio or video on this page. Please try again later.' keeps popping up on top of the screen.

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one with this problem. Did you find out anything?

Comment: Found this.... looks promising (will see in a few minutes): https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1660783.html

Comment: This worked: https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1661994.html

Comment: @eftshift0 Explain that in an answer and that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Followed the [link](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1660783.html) @eftshift0 suggested in a comment and it worked for me.

This is the part that was most helpful.

```
#check first what your profile is called and manually save it as
$firefox_profile ls -ld ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default
mkdir test
cd test
wget https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/widevine-cdm/4.10.1196.0-linux-x64.zip
unzip 4.10.1196.0-linux-x64.zip
rm -rf "${firefox_profile}"/gmp-widevinecdm/*
mkdir "${firefox_profile}"/gmp-widevinecdm/1.4.8.1008/
cp libwidevinecdm.so LICENSE.txt manifest.json "${firefox_profile}"/gmp-widevinecdm/1.4.8.1008/
```

What I actually did was downloading the zip file with my browser. 
https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/widevine-cdm/4.10.1196.0-linux-x64.zip

Find the folder where the outdated version of widevine is located. (Ctrl+H) 
Clicking... Home > .mozilla > firefox > the_folder_that_ends_with.default > gmp-widevinecdm > 1.4.8.1008 (only option for me at this point)

Unpack and overwrite the files with the archive manager to that folder, for me it was exactly the same filenames, different sizes. Replace all.

(Ctrl+H again :P)

I don't remember, but maybe you need to log out of of the profile and back in for it to work.

Comment: Yeah! It works! I've spent a week looking for this!

Comment: I just changed the line pref("app.update.channel", "default"); to pref("app.update.channel", "esr"); in channel-prefs.js in /usr/lib/firefox-esr/defaults/pref

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same issue, It happened after updating my system.

you can downgrade to 60.03esr-1~deb9u1. you can use aptitude to do so.